# Automated accent detection

Tags: audio

How can I compare the way that word is pronounced with a sample? For example, most of dictionaries have sample word pronunciation recorded. The goal is to provide feedback to the user so that he or she can improve pronunciation.

I wonder if there are API available for such task or existing programs that are able to do it.

I found similar question here [How do I compare 2 audio files, returning a percentage of difference](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1867/how-do-i-compare-2-audio-files-returning-a-percentage-of-difference) , but I am providing a definition what actual difference is.

Regards,
Eugene

Comment: Is your question asking for research references or code?

Answer (score 3):

That was the same topic of my Graduation Project, I am not yet sure of the best way to do it as this matter is still a research matter, but what my team and I did was as follow:

1- Provide a database representing the **features** of the right pronunciation of each word. This database contains for each word around 10 different features for 10 different people reading this word.

2- Get the **features** of the input word ie. a .wav file representing the word

3- compare the features of the input word with the 10 features representing the right pronunciation of the word

To get the features, you will need to get the MFCC file a .wav file containing the word pronounced
The MFCC is a matrix of numbers, so to compare 2 MFCCs, you will need to use dynamic programming algorithm, in our case we've use Dynamic Time Wrapping algorithm.
You might also need to make a filtering on the input words to filter them from noise.
You might also need to check for the following programs:
Praat  >> to make a filtering if needed, and also can be used to make MFCC file 
SPPAS  >> to get the feature of the .wav file (MFCC)
Matlab >> to compare 2 MFCC files

Hope this can help

Answer (score 0):

You have stated a problem roughly similar to speaker-independent isolated speech recognition into a dictionary of one word, where instead of searching for the closest word in the dictionary, you just want the multi-dimensional distance vector and/or match statistics. This is a non-trivial technology involving many thousands of research papers and books.  You might want to try a basic textbook on computer speech recognition to get started.

There does seem to  exist commercial software for automated accent analysis and improvement, but I am unfamiliar with them or whether any offer a public API.